# My git paths are prefixed with a cygdrive path even when in cmd

Tags: cmd, cygwin, git-bash

I have git bash installed, and now in the normal Windows CMD when running a command like `git clone`, the target path gets prefixed with a cygdrive path. How can I fix that?

```
git clone https://github.com/TencentARC/GFPGAN.git 'C:\ai\gan'
fatal: Invalid path '/cygdrive/c/Users/Felix/C:\ai\gan': No such file or directory
```

I just realized that this is not even the git version I have installed as "git for windows" (2.29), but rather:

```
C:\Users\Felix>git --version
git version 2.17.0

C:\Users\Felix>which git
/usr/bin/git
```

How would I get back a fully normal CMD without any cygwin paths? Even printing `$PATH` in CMD is full of cygdrive prefixes, which are not actually in the env var.

Comment: Did you check the .bashrc file? Or tried `echo $PATH`?

Comment: I'm not even in bash, just in the normal CMD now; I just uninstalled git for windows, but the cygwin stuff remains. I don't know how to uninstall it; it's not in my installed program list.

Comment: I am not used to Windows but I'd say that you've added an env variable to your system and when you call any variable everything comes along. You may want to get into /etc and edit the .bashrc file where all env variables are set. At least that's how I would do in Linux or OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Manually removing cygwin from the harddrive, all env vars, and the registry worked.